# Android Emulator turns off automatically after launching

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Android Virtual Device turns off automatically (it pops up only for a second and turns off right away)

I have been searching for answer for a while, but I have not found feasible answer yet.

Thanks in advance :)

My CPU is AMD and I turned on Hypervisor Platform.
My Android Studio version is 3.4.2

Comment: Have you tried turning graphics automatic into software?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer by myself. I am answering my own question for people with same problem.

I will list the background and procedure in chronological order below.

1. My CPU is AMD
2. I encountered the message goes "Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD. Your CPU does not support required features (VT-x or SVM)."
3. It turned out Android Studio DOES SUPPORT AMD since 2018. (not sure about exact time.)
4. I checked my settings from Android Studio and it DOES include the HAXM package.
5. The problem was my window was neither in i)developer mode nor using ii)"Windows Hypervisor Platform."
6. I utilized both from Control Panel

   i) developer mode: searched for "developer" from window

   ii) Windows Hypervisor Platform: Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> "Turn Windows Features On or Off" (from top left side) -> check "Windows Hypervisor Platform"
7. NOW, ADV started running.
8. BUT, shuts down after 1 second.
9. Thinking that there must be some updates I have to install since I changed my window setting to "developer" and started using "Windows Hypervisor Platform"
10. installed latest windows update from the following link 
    https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4512508
11. **FINALLY WORKING PROPERLY

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
Android Virtual Device Manager -> Actions(misbehaving AVD) -> Cool Boot Now

if it doesn't work for your case
try to read this document as well

https://www.bram.us/2017/05/12/fix-for-the-android-emulator-crashing-during-launch/

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! But I have found the answer from different source in different way.

Comment: @sanmariposa oh I see :) I hope you have a nice day!!